# How to ensure an app builder doesn't have acccess to database?

Tags: sql-server, azure, api, token, openid-connect

So, we have made a web application login protocol via which users can query a database on Azure SQL Server with sensitive data. Now partner-organizations want to use the same app to query their own databases on their own Azure SQL Server.

Is there a way where we can ensure that as admin + host of the web application we don't have access to their sensitive data, while we are able to send user from the correct Identity Provider through.

Until so far I found the OAuth 2.0 Token Introspection, specifically this implementation: https://wiki.surfnet.nl/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=23794471. Is there a way to implement this within Azure around the Azure SQL Server (if needed via a very simple API)?

Answer (score 0):

Azure built-in [reader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#reader) role:

> View all resources, but does not allow you to make any changes.

**EDIT:** If the problem is security you need to solve it through security countermeasure like [Always Encrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16):

> This provides a separation between those who own the data and can view
> it, and those who manage the data but should have no access -
> on-premises database administrators, cloud database operators, or
> other high-privileged unauthorized users.

Comment: ah great, this is one part of the answer, but I need to have no access at all (not even read access) the API in between could use this role.